# Android Studio 2.3.0 Gradle Project Refresh Failed profile-2017-03-12-17-53-22-268.rawproto

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu, gradle

I recently installed the new Android Studio update 2.3.0 on Ubuntu. I had to do it manually so I downloaded the update and executed studio.sh and imported settings from my old installation (2.2.3). Upon opening my project, I was asked if I wanted to use the SDK from before or the new SDK, so I chose the new SDK.

This all worked fine and I worked on my project. Next time I loaded Android Studio I accidentally opened the old installation and I was shown the gradle error below:

```
Gradle 'SimpleMessagingApp' project refresh failed
   Error:/home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppName/build/android-profile/profile-2017-03-12-17-53-22-268.rawproto
```

I tried to open on the new installation 2.3.0, and was then faced with the same error.

So far I have tried File > Invalidate Caches / Restart, and also tried deleting .gradle/caches.

I have only seen one other person with the problem on here and they have been down voted for lack of context, so I have tried to provide as much context as possible, but please let me know if you would like more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was reading  the log file (/home/username/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/log/idea.log) and noticed the line:

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppName/build/android-profile/profile-2017-03-12-18-50-37-494.rawproto
```

So I opened Android Studio with `sudo ./studio.sh` and everything works fine now. I'd rather not have to use sudo everytime so if anyone knows a better fix, please post a better answer.

Comment: You could `chmod 777` to some files so everyone has access

Comment: Yeah, `chmod 777` to /home/username/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppName/build fixed this, thank you

Comment: you sir are a genius, would've NEVER looked there.

Answer (score 0):

delete .Gradle file from app's folder.and recreate your gradle file.

Comment: This did not work, I am just faced with the same error

Answer (score 0):

**Steps To Run Applications as Root in Ubuntu**

1) Install gnome-panel type

```
sudo apt install gnome-panel
```

2) Open Terminal and type

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/Desktop/ --create-new
```

3) Now Create Launcher will appear

4) Set 
        Type: Application ; 
        Name : RunAsRoot ; 
    Command: /usr/bin/gksu
    Comment: